# pwrite: No space left on device. df -i, df -h okay

Tags: disk-space-utilization

On a Rackspace cloud server I see:

```
admin@foo:/etc/nginx$ sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start
Starting nginx: nginx: [crit] pwrite() "/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (28: No space left on device)
nginx.

admin@foo:/etc/nginx$ sudo df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       9.4G  6.6G  2.4G  74% /
udev             10M  8.0K   10M   1% /dev
none             25M   25M     0 100% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            123M     0  123M   0% /run/shm

admin@foo:/etc/nginx$ df -i
Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      1245184 154910 1090274   13% /
udev             31392    427   30965    2% /dev
none             31392   1374   30018    5% /run
none             31392      2   31390    1% /run/lock
none             31392      1   31391    1% /run/shm
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have indeed run out of space on `/run` (which is symlinked from `/var/run` on newer versions of Fedora and possibly other distributions). Check the directory and remove any unnecessary files, and consider giving it more space.

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't yet do that. When did fedora make that change?

Comment: @DennisKaarsemaker In [Fedora 15](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/15/html/Release_Notes/sect-Release_Notes-Changes_for_SysAdmin.html).

Comment: Ubuntu Precise, lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Jan 26 15:21 /var/run -> /run

Answer (score 1):

Is `/var/run` perhaps symlinked to `/run`?